# Php WebApp, Debugging breakpoints not working in aptana

Tags: php, aptana, breakpoints, xdebug, remote-debugging

I am using

- Aptana 3.5.0
- Php5.4
- PDT (Php developpeur tools) eclipse plugin

I also have wamp installed and everything is setting up correctly

**my php.ini**

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.idekey = "ECLIPSE_DBGP"
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

I can debug in Firefox with my Php Web Application debug configuration but can't make breakpoints to work the only way is to stop on first line which is not very helpful for Web debugging purpose

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve my issue :

I had PDT SDK, i switched to PDT, the one in that repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release

After launching has Web Application, breakpoints finnaly works